# Understanding a surprising GHC optimization of Haskell code

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, compiler-optimization

I was hacking around with some old Haskell code and stumbled upon a surprising optimization. After a little profiling I noticed the runtime spent a fair amount of time in the following function:

```
divisorCount = product . map ((+1).snd) . factorise'
```

I assumed that the majority of the work was being done in [**`factorise'`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Factorisation.html#v%3afactorise-39-), but for brevity's sake I should change the function to:

```
divisorCount = product . map (succ.snd) . factorise'
```

When I recompiled and reran the program, to my surprise the runtime went from `0.495s` to `0.325s`! That's a pretty significant speed increase!

Why did that simple change cause such a dramatic performance increase? What could GHC optimize in the second function that it could not in the first?

*Notes:*

- *using GHC version 7.6.3*
- *Both benchmarks were compiled with `-O2`*
- *Both benchmark runtimes were amortized over 10 trials*

Comment: Boilerplate question: which optimization level you used?

Comment: @duplode Can't believe I left that out, `-O2`

Comment: Looking at the GHC Core usually helps in these cases.

Comment: What I find extra surprising is that the `succ` definition from `instance Enum Int` actually checks whether its argument is `maxBound` before adding. Edit: I guess this probably means a strictness issue… maybe your first definition builds up thunks that are only evaluated by `product`, while the second version at least evaluates every number (up to the `(+1)`s, that is) before taking the product?

Comment: Try (1+) instead of (+1).

Comment: It would be nice if you wrote how did you call it. Because atm I am trying to reproduce it with `print $ show $ divisorCount1 1000000000000`, and it takes just ≈0.030s, and I am not sure at all how to force it to take more time.